# A and B are sets in a universe set U. Proof: If $A\cap B=\emptyset$ so $A\subseteq B^c$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I do this demonstration?

$A^c$ is A complement: $A'$

Please help me

What I'm doing is

$\forall x \in U: x\in A \subseteq x\in B^c$

therefore $\forall x \in U: x\in A \subseteq x\notin B$

$A\cap B = \emptyset \rightarrow  A\subseteq B^c$

$A\cap B = \emptyset \rightarrow  A\nsubseteq B$

Proof by Reductio ad absurdum

~($A\cup B= \emptyset)$

$A\cup B \neq \emptyset$

$\exists x \in A\cap B$

$x\in A \wedge x\in B$ this is a contradiction since element x is not in B

$\therefore $ Proof is valid

Comment: This is rather hard to follow. It helps to put each equation in context: is this statement a goal you're trying to reach? Is it an assumption? Does it follow from previous statements, and if so, how?

Comment: I apologize to you  @GregMartinAn I had a small error in lines 7 and 8, I put the complement of B and it was only B

Answer (score 2):

Heavens, you are overthinking this!

If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then no element $x$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$.

So if $x \in A$ then $x \notin B$, i.e. $x \in B^c$.

Hence $A \subseteq B^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the partition of the universe between $B$ and $B^c$ and the distributivity of intersection over union, as follows :
$$
A = A \cap U = A \cap (B \cup B^c) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = \emptyset \cup (A \cap B^c) = A \cap B^c \subseteq B^c
$$
*QED.*